# comments_where Hook

Tags: custom-field, comments, advanced-custom-fields, comment-meta, wp-comment-query

Is there a similar replacement of the hook [posts_where](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) for comments (`WP_Comment_Query`)?
I need to modify the where clause for a comments query like it is shown [in this tutorial (“4. Sub custom field values”)](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) for posts.
The only hook I found is [comments_pre_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_pre_query/), but the property `$query->meta_query_clauses[ 'where' ]` is protected.

Comment: the article you linked to seems to have been written by someone unaware of the `LIKE` operator in meta queries, likely because it is very old and at least 10 versions of WordPress out of date. I would treat this with a grain of salt, especially when the example uses the incorrect function to cleanup after `WP_Query` ( it should be `wp_reset_postdata` not `wp_reset_query` )

Comment: @TomJNowell Do you have a better idea to query for ACF Repeater field values?

Comment: the problem is how you stored the data, serialized data isn't meant to be queried, and the solution provided is not a full solution, e.g. if you're looking for `100` then `1000` will also match, `-100` `_100_` `241008` etc. That's on top of post meta already being slow to query for. As an aside were you sent here by other ACF users? 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here but there have been a lot of new ACF questions today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a quick search of developer.wordpress.org reveals `comment_feed_where`.

Note that this won't work with `get_posts` unless suppress filters is turned off, and that what you're trying to do is going to be very slow with some unreliability.

There is also `comment_clauses`:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_clauses/

Comment: I saw that hook, too, but is it also called along with get_comments()/WP_Comment_Query? The documentation mentions WP_Query, not WP_Comment_Query

Comment: there is a separate filter that passes an array of all the clauses

Comment: That works. Thank you!